# cakephp 3 and logout confusion

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, auth0

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around whether or not things are working as intended.

I've got a simple implementation of cakephp3, cake-auth0 (https://github.com/jsoftb/auth0) and I am using an auth0 login form.

This flow works just fine.

*example.com/users/login -> form -> my-domain.auth0.com -> example.com/users/login?code=secret*

```
$auth_code = $this->request->query('code', null);
if(!is_null($auth_code)) {
  $user = $this->Auth->identify();
  if($user) {
    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); // example.com/
  }
}
```

Logging a user out is where I'm having issues.

*example.com/users/logout -> auth0-domain (kill cookie) -> example.com*

```
public function logout() {
  return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
  // $this->redirect('http://auth0.domain?returnTo=http://example.com/');
}
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
  parent::beforeFilter($event);
  $this->Auth->allow('logout'); // Appears to do nothing
}
```

This successfully logs me in and out of auth0 just fine.
I stay logged into cake however and it is driving me a bit batty.
My login page with some session user output shows me as logged in and I can access the page example.com/users. I cannot view it while not yet logged in.

I haven't created any database stuff to go with users yet if that helps.

Short of going brutal and nuking all sessions/cookies using just php, anyone else have any ideas?

---

*Update:* Dug a lot through code. Cake's vanilla Authcomponent::logout doesn't do much of anything. I managed to get something that will work for me by manually killing *a* session of some sort.

I'll leave this up because I know some guru will come along at some point.

I was able to achieve logging out (of cake) like this:

```
public function logout() {
  $url = $this->Auth->logout();
  $this->request->session()->destroy();
  return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Call AuthComponent's logout function and save the response url string.

Destroy the request session because logout didn't do it.

Redirect.

Comment: If you are looking for help from people that do not neccesarily are auth0 experts, it might be worth adding a little more technical details about the actual login and logout flow, especially about the latter. From the code you are showing, I don't see how this would do anything other than clearing the CakePHP session storage when invoking the controllers `logout` method.

Comment: @ndm I don't think the issue has anything to do with auth0, unless the cake-auth0 plugin I am using has something incomplete with it.

Everything around auth0 is working, but when I try to access the logged in user's information after a logout I can still grab that information.

It is as if cake's auth logout does not work. I've run through a debugger and spat out information and it does reach the code that supposedly kills the session, but doesn't kill it.

Comment: Without knowledge about the exact flow it's hard to tell what might be going on, and all people can do is guessing. Again, from looking at the code I don't see how invoking `logout()` will affect anything other than the CakePHP auth session data, there doesn't seem to be anything that would affect possible auth0 session data (stored in the PHP session) in any way, leat alone auth0-side sessions. You say it does, but I have no information that would proof that satement, which doesn't make things easier.

Comment: In the scenario where only the CakePHP auth session data is affected, the auth component would probably pick up the user info being retrieved from auth0 session data again. That would possibly contradict your statement that you are being logged auth from auth0, but as I said I cannot determine whether that is actually the case, hence my shots in the dark. Adding some session debugging info might help too, like the exact session contents before the redirect, after the redirect, and then before and after the auth component starts up.

Comment: Auth0 is just using standard oauth stuff for login.
AuthComponent::logout() returns a url. With my auth0 setup that is the logout url they've given me, which terminates a particular user's authentication status with that app.

The process of authorizing a user with cake is done explicitly through my login method. I noticed the cake-auth0 plugin i'm using doesn't have an AuthComponent so I think there may just be an incompatibility of some kind that hasn't been worked out yet. 

Thank you for your time. Strapped on time myself, so I just killed the session myself. Hopefully without issues.